# If you download gsl with vcpkg how can you modify a source file of a library such as trust.c

Tags: c, visual-studio, least-squares, gsl, model-fitting

As the title says , I downloaded the gsl library using vcpkg . Vcpkg includes and links the library automatically. So how can I modify source files such as trust.c and make sure that my program in visual studio uses the modified file and not the original one ?
Is there a way to do it using vcpkg?

I did try to do .\vcpkg edit gsl in cmdr but it told me I don't have access to that .
I would appreciate any help with this.